# How to center popup form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a popup contact form on my website that is almost centered but appearing a little too high and a little too much to the right.

Here's the CSS for it:

```
#fg_formContainer
{
   height:410px;
   width:545px;
   background:#FFFFFF;
   border:1px solid #000;
   padding:0;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:999;
   cursor:default;   
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;   
display:none;
}
```

You can go to envisionlocal[dot]com and click on the "Get In Touch" text to see the popup form.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: when u say center are you talking vertical center as well. do you need only css or can script be used.

Comment: margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;

Comment: I would prefer it be centered at least horizontally, being centered vertically isn't that big of a deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have:

```
display: block;
top: 174px;
left: 519px;
```

To center it, change left to 50% and set a margin-left negative 1/2 the container width (545 px)

So,

```
display: block;
top: 174px;
left: 50%;
margin-left:-272px;
```

Comment: Where are you seeing `display: block;` or any of the other code you said that I already had?

Comment: @user2410854 To answer the above, it is being applied INLINE : <div id="fg_formContainer" style="display: block; top: 201px; left: 645px; margin-left: -272px; margin-top: -205px;">

Comment: It appears inline. It's being added from fg_moveable_popup, when I drag my browser window and refresh it changes the left value. The line:var pt = window.center({width:390,height:480}); in fg_moveable_popup seems to be the base for what's generating this style. Seeing as this is a third party script, have you adjusted the size of the DIV #fg_formContainer from their sample?

Comment: Worth mentioning, while working with this, window widths under 900px cause your content to break and overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You are using absolute positioning and setting specific pixel values to the `top:` and `left:` properties.  To center these values should be 50%.  This creates it's issue, as the properties `top:` and `left:` are calculated from the top edge and left edge of the element they are being applied to, respectively.  To "fake" the element into calculating 50% from it's center, simply add a `margin-top:` and `margin-left:` that is equal to half of that elements width and height respectively.

Add the below rules to center bother horizontally and vertically.

```
display: block;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -272px;
margin-top: -205px;
```

**EDIT:**

In reference to your comment below as well as a comment on someone elses answer which is similar to mine.  Some of your styles are being applied inline.

Your container div: `<div id="fg_formContainer" style="display: block; top: 201px; left: 645px; margin-left: -272px; margin-top: -205px;">`

If you change the `top:` and `left:` values to 50%, my fix will work for you.

Furthermore... These styles should be applied to the CSS block you posted above.  They should NOT be applied inline in the first place.

Comment: Ok that is the closest I've gotten it to working.  When you first click on it the box is at the very top and almost out of slight.  But when you refresh the page, you can see it go to the center for a split second.

Comment: @user2410854 There is something over-writing your top: and left: values.  They show as this for me: top: 201px; and left: 645px;

They both should be 50%.  Your CSS isn't being applied correctly somewhere, or you didn't change the top and left values to 50%.

Answer (score 0):

In your JS file, http://www.envisionlocal.com/scripts/fg_moveable_popup.js, you need to update the width and height of a function with the actual width and height of your object.

This code here :

var pt = window.center({
        width: 390,
        height: 480
    });

should be:

var pt = window.center({
        width: 410,
        height: 545
    });

I believe that should do the trick. Your js function, fg_popup_form, is handling the center for you. It runs this function, called window.center(), that centers your popup. However if you don't enter the correct width and height of your popup element, it won't position itself correctly.

Yes, you can do this differently via CSS, but your JS is already in place to achieve this.

Comment: Tried that and it raised the box up a bit higher and more tot he right.

Comment: Did you have a Web inspector open? Thats' what happened to me when I had the Chrome inspector open... when I closed the web inspector it positioned correctly.  This is a third-party script, I presume. It works, but you may as well use a jqeury plugin script for this instead... check this one out: http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I made this for a friend. This might help you.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/sonu/pen/bBxFC)

HTML:

```
<div id="fblightbox">
  <div class="fblightbox-wrap">
    <div class="fblightbox-header">
      <h3>This header is just awesome xD</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="fblightbox-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fblightbox-footer">
      <a href="#" class="fbbutton">Continue</a>
      <a href="#" id="close" class="fbbutton">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>

<div class="demo">
  <a id="launch" class="fbbutton" href="#">Launch Popup</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#fblightbox{
  background: rgba(82, 82, 82, .7);
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding:10px;
  width: 575px;
  position: fixed;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  z-index: 99999;
  display:none;
}
.fblightbox-wrap{
  border: 1px solid #3B5998;
}
.fblightbox-header{
  background:#6C83B8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #29447E;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding:5px;
}
.fblightbox-header h3{
  font-size:14px;
}
.fblightbox-content{
  background:#fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding:10px;
}
.fblightbox-footer{
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align:right;
}
.fbbutton{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/tu8qPWG.png);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-position: 125px 235px;
  border-color: #29447E #29447E #1A356E;
  line-height: normal !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
.overlay{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  display:none;
}

.demo{
  padding:30px 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
var fblightbox = $('#fblightbox');
fblightbox.css({'margin-left':'-'+(fblightbox.width()/2)+'px','margin-top':'-'+(fblightbox.height()/2)+'px'});

$("#launch").click(function() {
  $('.overlay').fadeIn();
  fblightbox.fadeIn();
});
$("#close").click(function() {
  $('.overlay').fadeOut();
  fblightbox.fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery you could do:

```
jQuery.fn.centerThat = function () {
    this.css('position','absolute');
    this.css('top', Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + 
        $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
    this.css('left', Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) +
        $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px');
    return this;
};
```

Now you can use this function to center any element in the window, like this:

```
$('#fg_formContainer').centerThat();
```

Comment: I have no idea how to add that but if you could take the time to explain it further I'd definitely like to try it out.

Comment: The code above is OK with dynamic size containers, which is impossible to achieve with CSS alone. It's an automation of what the CSS is doing... when he knows the dimensions, that is ;-) Maybe a little overkill for the issue here but can be considered if needed elsewhere or..?

Comment: ...funny to see that an answer THAT IS WORKING deserve a downvote ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to Vertical centering and `margin-left:auto, margin-right:auto` to Horizontal center

```
vertical-align: middle;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
```

Comment: This will not work on the basis he is using position: absolute;  Did you even test this?